# How do I get current ionic mode from code

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

I am using Angular 9 together with ionic5 and I need to get the currently used mode (string `md` or `ios` which can be different from platform) from my typescript code. So my question is that if this is possible directly from typescript code without the need of reading it from the tag html `mode` attribute.

I tried to consult the official documentation on [Platform styles](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/platform-styles), but this only considers usage inside CSS.

Comment: How is md (Android) and ios (Apple) not related to the platform?

Comment: "Each platform has a default mode, but this can be overridden through the global config." [Ionic Modes](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/platform-styles#ionic-modes) . From that I take that it is not guarenteed that the mode will correspond to the platform.

Comment: have you tried it and actually verified that theory? Seems like platform will report whatever is loaded.....including overrides to the default config.

Comment: For that you have to use `mode="{{YourModeVariable}}"` from your ts. and inside your `ts` you can defined which one to use  `YourModeVariable = 'md | ios';` then you will know which mode you are using and change is dynamically.

Comment: @E.Maggini unfortunately, when I set `IonicModule.forRoot({mode:'md'}),` inside `app.module.ts`, `this.platform.platforms()` still returns `[ "iphone", "ios", "mobile", "mobileweb" ]` .

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib Could you please elaborate? I want to obtain the globally defined mode, that can be seen as the `mode` attribute of the `html` tag.

Comment: for that you have to explain your requirement. Why you want to get mode?

Comment: Right now I need it for a modification of the ion-datepicker component - I want to add a button, that will clear currently selected value. I am copying the button that is used inside ion-input, but for styling it correctly, I need to assing it a class ending with `-md` or `-ios`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to find these things is by taking a look at the Ionic's source code, specially the `providers` folder. There, I found the following file: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/blob/master/angular/src/providers/config.ts

That file exposes the `Config` provider, that will expose the entire configuration of the app, including the `mode`.

Please take a look at this **[working Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-66263854?file=src/app/pages/home/home.page.ts)**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Config } from "@ionic/angular";

@Component({
  selector: "app-home",
  templateUrl: "./home.page.html",
  styleUrls: ["./home.page.scss"]
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit {
  public mode: string;

  constructor(private config: Config) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // Replace the mode in the app.module.ts
    // file to test this
    this.mode = this.config.get("mode");
  }
}
```

Comment: This works great, exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The Platform service can be used to get information about your current device. You can get all of the platforms associated with the device using the platforms method, including whether the app is being viewed from a tablet, if it's on a mobile device or browser, and the exact platform (iOS, Android, etc). You can also get the orientation of the device, if it uses right-to-left language direction, and much much more. With this information you can completely customize your app to fit any device.

[For more information](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/platform)

Comment: Thanks! But according to [Ionic Modes](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/platform-styles#ionic-modes) ("Each platform has a default mode, but this can be overridden through the global config.") it is not guaranteed, that the mode will correspond to the plaform used. Or am I getting something wrong?